# Can you graph equations with a negative discriminant? And how do you plot complex numbers both on a 2D complex plane and a 4D complex plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I don't understand the relationship between complex numbers and that way they are graphed. The equation I am working with is $2x^{2} - 6x + 5 = 0$ where my two roots are complex solutions: $x = (3/2)-(i/2)$ and $x = (3/2)+(i/2)$.  From what I understand, there is different dimensional space where these roots can be plotted due to the fundamental theorem of algebra. Although I don't quite fully understand the fundamental theorem of algebra apart from that a complex polynomial of degree $n$ has precisely $n$ roots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've added [mathematical markup](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to your question; please feel free to edit if I've misconstrued anything.  As stated, it's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking: Do you merely want to plot complex numbers? Do you want to visualize the graph of a complex polynomial (a surface in four-dimensional space)? Something else...?

Comment: HI! Basically various things. I understand how to plot complex numbers onto a 2d complex plane, but how and why would I need to do it on a 4d plane? I also want to know the relationship between plotting complex numbers, and the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A different color is the usual way. You plot everything multiplied by $i$ in a different color than the real part.

Try plotting Euler's identity in mathematica; `Plot[E^(I x), {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}]` which is $$y=\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$$ to get a better understanding of what I'm saying.

To your original question, the roots of a polynomial with a negative discriminant can be marked as different colored points in the real plane or be put in a complex plane. For the  4D part, you can 3D plot a colored contour similar to the way you plot a 2D representation of a 3D object by using contour plots but reading that to get information out of it might require a lot of work.